# UIView equivalent in Android

Tags: android, xamarin

I am trying to convert the following code from Xamarin ios to Xamarin Android.

I want to know what is `UIView` equivalent in Android?

The following code is written in `xamarin.ios` and I need to convert to `xamarin.android`

```
public UIView View {get {return cView;}}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The core UI element in Android is the [View](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/)

Comment: Thanks a lot Jason, I have upvoted and will mark your answer once SOF allows.